# Snakes and ladders

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

There are 9 game states(the 9 squares) and 1 state off the board(state o) where play begins.
[image]

The question is: the minimum number of moves required to win the game?

I did a transition matrix, but after i don't have an idea what to do.

Comment: What are the rules for movement?  The version I knew had many more squares and you rolled dice for the number to move.

Comment: Heads: move forward one space (probability 0.5)

Comment: Tails: move forward two space( probability 0.5)

Answer (score 0):

The minimum is four.  If you throw a head and a tail in either order to start you climb the ladder, then two more tails get you to $9$.  Did you mean to ask the expected number of moves until you win?

Comment: yes, I logically got the same answer.

Comment: But how can i explain, using transition matrix and markov chains?

Comment: Random moves and minimum moves are two different things.  You don't need a Markov chain for minimum moves, you just need to justify that there is no shorter path.  Clearly one can only get to $9$ from $7$, so you need the shortest path there.  Keep working backwards and you will find the solution I gave.